# How to get state of aggregate from another aggregate or saga

Tags: aggregate, cqrs, saga, axon

I'm working with Axon 4, and can't understand the following thing.
If I am handling a command in aggregate, I can read it's state, but what if I need to know some property of another aggregate?

Here is an example, I want to assign to person a task from queue, and have Person aggregate and Queue aggregate.

```
@Aggregate
class PersonAggregate {

  UUID id; //fields are just example
  UUID currentTaskId

  @CommandHandler
  public void handle(AssignFreeTaskCommand cmd) { 
//Need to get info about tasks here, queue aggregate is known from projection, as new queue are rare added (but task I'd is not)... }

}




@Aggregate
class QueueAggregate {

  UUID id; //fields are just example
  List<UUID> tasks;


}
```

I've read about Saga, but also did not get, if we can get state of aggregate in Saga also.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject into your aggregate as you would do with any other bean ... so if you need to gather additional information to decide if and how a command should be handled, just inject the required repos/services and use them.

In your case, this might be the aggregateRepository of the other aggregate. But it's possibly a better idea to use a read model/projection and query that for the required information rather than relying on the internal state of another aggregate directly.

Comment: An addition to this answer: if you adopt CQRS, you should never access aggregate state for queries. In the question, you specify that you need to get information from another aggregate. A command model should not be designed around providing information about its state. Instead, use a Query model.

Comment: But i see problem here. Please, correct me if i'm wrong, but query - side is not 'golden source', so, state of query service can be inconsistent instead of state of domain service(service with aggregates).

Comment: Yes of course, everything is eventual consistent only. But even if you call the aggregate directly, you can’t know for sure. It might be in the middle of a complex unit of work and show only outdated information.  When you Beils a query projection inside your aggregate handling component you could possibly minimize the lack.

Answer (score 0):

This would strongly suggest you need to look at your aggregate root design. In essence, an aggregate is responsible for its own integrity. If it relies on outside information it can no longer do this. Slightly more subtly, you are also likely to add accidental complexity to your code.

Aggregate do NOT look like data models. And this is the hardest part for developers when learning and designing AG for the first time. We are generally so used to thinking in terms of tables and relations.

Apologies if this next suggestion sounds like I'm teaching you to suck eggs but I didn't realise this for some time. They are called 'Aggregates' because they can aggregate more than one class together in order to carry out their work. The key point is that you can only make changes to the state of any of those classes through the aggregate root.

So the short answer is: Have another look at your aggregate root design.

Comment: Can you please introduce some kind of example for my situation? What is wrong in my design?